# How to solve exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: wordpress, segmentation-fault

After I migrated wordpress from a shared host to my own VPS I got the unpleasant surprise that half of the back-end pages on my websites rendered a `No data receive ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Determined to find out what caused the problem I started troubleshooting. 7 of my 8 websites were affected, all running wordpress 4.1.5. Upgrading to 4.2.2 did not fix the problem.

The only unaffected website is an old website running on wordpress 3.3.1. Upgrading this website to run 4.2.2 results in the same errors. When I try to do a fresh wordpress install the same error pops up after step one (both when installing 4.2.2 and 3.3.1).

The 7 sites are running on 4 different themes, and I tried dis-enabling all plugins, still no luck.

I had a look at the error logs, I will copy a fragment here since they might provide some useful info. I've been googling all these lines but can't find the solution yet.

```
[Sun Jun 21 10:22:41 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down  
[Sun Jun 21 10:22:42 2015] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled   
[Sun Jun 21 10:22:42 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost' does NOT match server name!? 
[Sun Jun 21 10:22:42 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Jun 21 10:22:43 2015] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Sun Jun 21 10:22:43 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost' does NOT match server name!?
[Sun Jun 21 10:22:43 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips DAV/2 PHP/5.2.17 configured -- resuming normal operations   
[Sun Jun 21 10:22:59 2015] [notice] child pid 3943 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)    
[Sun Jun 21 10:23:00 2015] [notice] child pid 3944 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)    
[Sun Jun 21 10:23:02 2015] [notice] child pid 3945 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)    
[Sun Jun 21 10:23:03 2015] [notice] child pid 3942 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)    
[Sun Jun 21 10:23:04 2015] [notice] child pid 4080 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)    
[Sun Jun 21 10:23:05 2015] [notice] child pid 3946 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)    
[Sun Jun 21 10:23:06 2015] [notice] child pid 4083 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)   
[Sun Jun 21 10:23:07 2015] [notice] child pid 4082 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Comment: I just restored an old backup without varnish. Before installing varnish everything worked fine.

Comment: I solved the problem. I fixed the "Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel" by updating the ssl certificates (read that solution somewhere). I found the right solution on this website: 

https://community.hpcloud.com/article/centos-63-instance-giving-cannot-retrieve-metalink-repository-epel-error

Now everything seems to work perfectly.